# What is the max character length of Entity Id?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a limit to how many characters an Entity Identifier can be? The only mention I can find of it is here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#assigning_identifiers. However, it seems I can have a string identifier of almost any length when I try to make an entity.

If there is no limit to how many characters an Entity Identifier can be, is there a performance trade off if the Identifier is short versus long? Integer versus String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id for an entity is part of a key, so the [limit is 6 KiB](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits) for the entire key, including all ids & kinds.

Comment: I see, so essentially the key + id could be hundreds of characters long since 1 KiB is 1024 bytes. This is fairly large.